# Vim help on Emacs using evil-mode?

Tags: evil, help

It would be nice to have the help system present in Vim when using Emacs evil-mode (`:help` command). I searched online and could not find a way to do this since only the native Emacs `C-h` help menu is available. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a `vim-help-mode` for that in [this repo](https://github.com/dalanicolai/dala-emacs-lisp#vim-helpel). Instead of using the `:help` ex-command, it provides the command `(M-x) vim-help` to find a subject. Within the vim help files, it provides `M-x vim-help-find-tag` (or `C-]`) for finding tags, or when you have the [link-hint library](https://github.com/noctuid/link-hint.el) installed, you can 'follow' tags by pressing `o`.

Comment: Please summarize here what that links says about `vim-help-mode`. Otherwise this is essentially a link-only answer. Thx.